# How can I evaluate a math expression given as a list of strings?

Tags: python, list, parsing, operator-keyword

I have a list of tokens like this:

```py
tokens = ["6", "+", "8"]
result = calculate(tokens) # ?
```

And I would like to create a `calculate` function that would evaluate the result of this expression.

I attempted to do something like:

```
while has_operator(tokens):
    operator_str, operator_pos = find_next_operator(tokens)
    left = tokens[operator_pos - 1] # Number to the left of operator
    right = tokens[operator_pos + 1]                 # to the right
    result = evaluate(left, right, operator_str)     # Eval function
    tokens[operator_pos-1:operator_pos+2] = [result] # Replace back
final_result = int(tokens[0])

# eg: ['2', '*', '3', '+', '4']
#     ['6', '+', '4'] 
#     ['10'] 
#     result =  10
```

At the end, the list would reduce to a single value, the answer.

How would this work when both operators and numbers are stored in the same array?

How would I be able to convert the operator string in a real operator?

Comment: You need to write a parser. It's not an easy task. However, it can be good exercise. Be aware of operation priorities.

Comment: Why over complicate things? `sum([int(i) for i in ["6", "8"]])`

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution (that of course might be over engineered) would be converting your input to [Reverse Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org//wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) and then calculating it.

Since you mentioned that you were given a list of strings, I am going to infer that you already have a tokenizer.

`string` → `string[]`
eg: `"(1 + 3 * 4) - 5"` → `['(','+','3','*','4',')', '-','5']`

My first step would be declaring a map of supported operations.
`string` → `operation`

```py
from math import *
from collections import namedtuple

OpBehaviour = namedtuple('OpBehaviour', 'priority lmbd')
# Maps an operation to a tuple containing 
# (Order of operation, implementation)
operations = {
    "+": OpBehaviour(0, lambda x, y: y+x),
    "-": OpBehaviour(0, lambda x, y: y-x),
    "/": OpBehaviour(1, lambda x, y: y/x),
    "*": OpBehaviour(1, lambda x, y: y*x),
    "!": OpBehaviour(2, lambda x: gamma(1+x)),
    "^": OpBehaviour(2, lambda x, y: y**x)
}
```

Now for the tricky part, converting our tokens into RPN form.

In my solution, I have used a simplified version of the [Shunting yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm).
Note that my implementation will not work with unbalanced brackets.

```py
def to_rpn(tokens):
    rpn_tokens = []
    op_stack = []

    for token in tokens:
        # Add number to rpn tokens
        if (is_float(token)):
            rpn_tokens.append(token)
        # Add opening bracket to operation stack
        elif token == "(":
            op_stack.append(token)
        # Consumes all operations until matching opening bracket
        elif token == ")":
            while op_stack[-1] != "(":
                rpn_tokens.append(op_stack.pop())
            op_stack.pop()
        elif token in list(operations.keys()):
            try:
                # Check if we have operations that have higher priority on
                # the op_stack and add them to rpn_tokens so that they are evaluated first:
                token_priority = operations[token].priority
                while op_stack[-1] != "(" and operations[op_stack[-1]].priority >= token_priority:
                    rpn_tokens.append(op_stack.pop())
            except IndexError:  # op_stack is empty
                pass

            # Add the current operation to the op_stack:
            op_stack.append(token)

    # Add remaining operations to rpn tokens
    while len(op_stack) != 0:
        rpn_tokens.append(op_stack.pop())

    return rpn_tokens
```

Then we calculate the RPN tokens by adding and popping values from the stack.

```
def calculate(rpn_tokens):
    val_stack = []

    for token in rpn_tokens:
        if (is_float(token)):
            val_stack.append(token)
        elif token in list(operations.keys()):
            args = []
            # How many arguments does our lambda have?
            arg_count = operations[token].lmbd.__code__.co_argcount
            for x in range(arg_count):
                args.append(float(val_stack.pop()))
            # Evaluate expression and add result to stack
            result = operations[token].lmbd(*args)
            val_stack.append(result)
 
    # If the value stack is bigger than one we probably made an error
    return val_stack[0]
```

You can then glue everything together as such:

```
def calculate_string(string):
    tokenized = tokenize(string)
    rpn = to_rpn(tokenized)
    return calculate(rpn)
```

You can find my complete working example [here](https://gist.github.com/SeoFernando25/da9d662633e02dec385aef5412a3119c).

I recommend you reading more about the Shunting yard algorithm, Reverse Polish Notation and perhaps debugging it step-by-step to better understand how my solution works.

Answer (score 0):

To access operators programmatically, you can just use the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module.

For example:

```
import operator


def op2fn(text):
    if text == "+":
        return operator.add
    elif text == "-":
        return operator.sub


l = ["6", "+", "8"]
result = op2fn(l[1])(int(l[0]), int(l[2]))
print(result)
# 14
```

---

Alternatively, you can use your own function, e.g.:

```
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

---

Note that this answer only address the issue of mapping `"+"` to the `operator.add` function. If you want to write a parser, this is only the simplest part of it.

Answer (score 0):

**Code:-**

```
x = ['1','+','2','-','3']
check=0
for i in x:
    if i in ["+","-","*","/"]:
        check+=1
for i in range(len(x)+check-1): #Assuming The sign (+,-) where present has previous and forward numbers 
    if x[i]=="+":
        temp1=int(x[i-1])+int(x[i+1])
        x.insert(i+2,str(temp1))
    if x[i]=="-":
        temp2=int(x[i-1])-int(x[i+1])
        x.insert(i+2,str(temp2))
    if x[i]=="*":
        temp3=int(x[i-1])*int(x[i+1])
        x.insert(i+2,str(temp3))
    if x[i]=="/":
        temp4=int(x[i-1])//int(x[i+1])
        x.insert(i+2,str(temp4))
#print(x)   #values how store in the list
print(x[-1])
```

**Updated photo:-**
[image]

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your time but when I try to run the code it returns a syntax error without mentioning at which line the syntax error is. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Which python version you are using.. I am using 3.7